# Turbo, adding params to post or other types of Turbo data not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using Turbo which you can find more information about it here: https://www.turbo360.co/docs

What I am trying to do is to attach a parameter to a Post before it is created. In this case I am trying to attach a profile. I am not getting any errors and from what I see the param is going through just fine, but when I log out the post the `profile` param is not there.

Here is creating the post:

```
createPost(params) {
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;
    if (currentUser == null) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'Please Login or Register before posting',
        type: 'error'
      });
      return;
    }

    params['profile'] = currentUser;
    console.log(params);
    this.props
      .createPost(params)
      .then(data => {
        swal({
          title: 'Post Created',
          text: `Title: ${data.title}`,
          type: 'success'
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Here is the action createPost:

```
createPost: params => {
    return dispatch => {
      return dispatch(TurboClient.createPost(params, constants.POST_CREATED));
    };
  },
```

Here is the TurboClient function createPost:

```
const postRequest = (resource, params, actionType) => {
  return dispatch =>
    turbo({ site_id: APP_ID })
      .create(resource, params)
      .then(data => {
        if (actionType != null) {
          dispatch({
            type: actionType,
            data: data
          });
        }

        return data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
};

const createPost = (params, actionType) => {
  return postRequest('post', params, actionType);
};
```

Now from here you can see where I log the params, this returns: 
[image]

Here is what the post looks like once it is created:
[image]

Comment: i do see a profile key in your screenshot though

Comment: Those are the params logged before the post is created. When the post is created it is not there, let me add that in an edit

Comment: can you post the code of `this.props.createPost(params)` then?

Comment: @Sag1v that should be everything, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a Post object. In your createPost method you return:
`postRequest('post', params, actionType);`

By using the word 'post' here you are creating it as a Post object, which has a very specific schema that it follows. If you would like to change that, you could try creating a Custom Object by doing something like this, for example:

`postRequest('randomName', params, actionType);`

Hope that helps.